# Strict Jensen inequality for Ergodic Markov processes

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory, jensen-inequality, contraction-mapping

Let $\vartheta(t)$ be a real Ergodic stationary Markov process solution to the stochastic differential equation
$$
\mathrm{d}\vartheta(t)=A_1(\vartheta(t),t)\mathrm{d}t+A_2(\vartheta(t),t)\mathrm{d}W(t)
$$
where $A_1,A_2$ are unknown $\sigma$-finite measurable functions and $W(t)$ is the standard Brownian motion satisfying the usual conditions. Assume that there exists a finite constant $C$ such that
$$
|A_1(x)-A_1(y)|+|A_2(x)-A_2(y)|\leq C|x-y|
$$
for any $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and that $\vartheta(t)$ is $\rho$-mixing with exponentially decaying $\rho$-mixing coefficient $\rho_t(\cdot)$ and strong mixing coefficient $\alpha(\ell)\leq\rho(\ell)$ for any integer $\ell$. Moreover, assume that the conditional density $p_{n}(x\mid y)$ of $\vartheta(t+n)$ given $\vartheta(t)$ is continuous in the arguments $(x,y)$ and bounded by a constant $c$ independent of $n$ and that the unconditional density $p(x)$ is continuous, bounded and time-invariant.

From Jensen's inequality, we know that the conditional operator $\mathbb{E}(\vartheta(t)\mid\mathcal{F}_t)$ is a contraction mapping, where $\mathcal{F}_t$ denotes the usual filtration equipped on the underlying probability space. My question is if, provided that $\vartheta(t)\neq\mathbb{E}\vartheta$, the inequality becomes strict? That is,
$$
\varphi(\mathbb{E}(\vartheta(t)\mid\mathcal{F}_t))<\mathbb{E}(\varphi(\vartheta(t))\mid\mathcal{F}_t),\quad\vartheta(t)\neq\mathbb{E}\vartheta
$$
for $\varphi$ a convex function.

To the best of my knowledge, I couldn't find any theory that connects ergodicity to strict contractions for real stationary ergodic Markov processes, or any stochastic process for matter. Any help in the form of tips, proofs, contradictions or references are welcome, thank you in advance!

For some additional context, the model is used in the paper by Fan, Fan and Lv [Aggregation of Nonparametric Estimators for Volatility Matrix](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0701107.pdf) for their aggregated estimator for the diffusion operator using a kernel estimator, which requires the above conditions, among others, to be satisfied. From an economic perspective, it can be useful to have a quantitative measure on whether a process is mean reverting. From the above mentioned paper, it is achieved to test whether the process $\vartheta(t)$ is stationary, yet if this implies that the process in expectation is pulled back to its unconditional mean is not discussed.

Comment: I think the least you'll have to assume is that $\phi$ is strictly convex. Otherwise you can just take $\phi$ to be linear and then clearly the two quantities are equal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @SmallDeviation. If we take $\varphi$ to be $|\cdot|^2$, which is clearly convex yet not strictly convex, I would still wonder if the inequality will be strict provided that $\vartheta(t)\neq\mathbb{E}\vartheta$? And more interestingly, would this imply that the process is mean reverting?

Comment: $|\cdot|^2$ *is* strictly convex. Perhaps you mean $|\cdot|$, which is convex but not strictly convex. If your random variable $\vartheta$ has a Riemann density, then the inequality $\phi(\mathbb E\vartheta)\leq \mathbb E\phi(\vartheta)$ should be strict. Though i am not entirely sure about the conditional expectation. I suspect it is a strict inequality as well, but i am not sure how to show it.